# Failed to connect to Elasticsearch server

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, bitnami

I installed latest version of ELK stack on Azure (7.0.1). I have apm-server on kubernetes with this docker image: `docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:7.0.1`

But, it's not connecting with elasticsearch server.

Error:

> ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://x.x.x.x:9200)): Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: This Beat requires the default distribution of Elasticsearch. Please upgrade to the default distribution of Elasticsearch from elastic.co, or downgrade to the oss-only distribution of beats
>
> INFO    pipeline/output.go:93   Attempting to reconnect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://x.x.x.x:9200)) with 11 reconnect attempt(s)
>
> INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/retry.go:189   retryer: send unwait-signal to consumer
>
> INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/retry.go:191     done
>
> INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/retry.go:166   retryer: send wait signal to consumer
>
> INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/retry.go:168     done
>
> INFO    elasticsearch/client.go:734     Attempting to connect to Elasticsearch version 7.0.1
>
> INFO    [request]       beater/common_handler.go:185    handled request {"request_id": "2e79d623-b8fb-4743-8b50-b516db256d5b", "method": "POST", "URL": "/intake/v2/events", "content_length": -1, "remote_address": "10.0.11.11", "user-agent": "elastic-apm-node/2.11.0 elastic-apm-http-client/7.3.0", "response_code": 202}

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the oss distribution of elasticsearch but the defaut version of apm.

upgrade the elasticsearch cluster to the default disto or use this oss apm docker image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server-oss:7.0.1

Comment: It's running fine with elasticsearch version 6.7.1 and image `docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:`6.6.1`. I am not using oss image there.